# ABAP module pool program issue

Tags: screen, abap

I am doing my praticals in module pool programs.

I want to know actual working of PBO and PAI 
when are they called,
and how the processing follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBO: process before output
PAI: process after input

So each time the user clicks a button, or hits the enter key, the program goes through the PAI part, then through the PBO part, and then displays the next screen waiting for the next user action.
You can set break-points in each section to see for yourself when the program goes through them.

Comment: SO IF WE WANT TO HANDLE A BUTTON CLICK EVENT WE SHOULD WRITE IT IN  PBO EVENT ?

Comment: No, in the PAI section. Typically you create a user_command module in the PAI section, which handles the received sy-ucomm value.

Answer (score 0):

`PBO` is process before output, that means it will load the screen and field that you have written in `PBO` or in `include O01`.

When screen is loaded and the user performs any action, gives input or hits any button, then `PAI` gets triggered, whoser actions are defined in `include IO1`.